# In Ember.js, what is the context of a view when ENV.VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT is enabled?

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation in a template where I want to use an if block on a value in the parent context while inside an each block.

From the Ember.js View Layer guide (http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/):

> Handlebars helpers in Ember may also specify variables. For example, the {{#with controller.person as tom}} form specifies a tom variable that descendent scopes can access. Even if a child context has a tom property, the tom variable will supersede it.
>
> This form has one major benefit: it allows you to shorten long paths without losing access to the parent scope.
>
> It is especially important in the {{#each}} helper, which provides a {{#each person in people}} form. In this form, descendent context have access to the person variable, but remain in the same scope as where the template invoked the each.

I also enabled the flags `ENV.CP_DEFAULT_CACHEABLE` and `ENV.VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT`.

The code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.view = Ember.View.extend({
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: true
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.view}}
        {{log foo}} {{! this will log "undefined"}}
        {{#each array in foo}}
            {{#each number in array}}
                {{#if bar}}
                    {{number}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

This does not work. I am not sure why. Logging `foo` will print "undefined". Why is `foo` undefined? What is the context of the root view?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hekevintran/sMeyC/10/

I am pretty sure that this is related to `ENV.VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT` because when I disable that I can make it work by referring to `bar` as `parentView.bar`.

Working demo where `ENV.VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT` is disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/hekevintran/sMeyC/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now in Ember when you have a view with an anonymous template any `{{property}}` calls with go to the parent view. In other words, `{{#view}}` will no longer change the context of the view. It's context will be that of the parent.

See the tldr examples over here: https://gist.github.com/2494968

So in order to get your code working we will have to access foo and bar by using `view.foo` and `view.bar` since we want to fetch those properties in the context of the `{{#view App.view}}`.

Here is an updated fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/cRgag/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.view}}
        {{log view.foo}} {{! this will log "undefined"}}
        {{#each view.foo}}
            {{#each this}}
                {{#if view.bar}}
                    {{this}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}           
        {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

PS: It looks like `{{log view.foo}}` does not work. You should probably file a bug report over on github.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The logger lying to me didn't help. I filed a bug report for that. I assume that views that have named templates can refer to their properties plainly without `view.`?

Comment: correct. using {{view}} will change the context, but {{#view}} won't.

Comment: thanks for bringing this up - I put together a pull request to fix {{log}} - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/863